# Hide side menu even if the current router link clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am using (angular2) want to hide the side menu on clicking any of its links.

I read [this question & its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044114/angular-hide-sidebar-menu-after-clicking-a-menu-item) referenced in [this article](https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/detecting-router-changes-with-angular-2-2f8c019788c3).

the solution works good if the user click on `[routerLink]`  other than the currently active one. but ith the current active link is clicked no event emitted.

this is the code:

```
constructor(
      private router: Router,
      public zone: NgZone) {
      router.events.subscribe( (event: Event) => {

          if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
              // Show loading indicator
          }

          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
              // Hide loading indicator
              this.w3_close(); // function to hide the menu
          }

          if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
              // Hide loading indicator
              // Present error to user
              console.log(event.error);
          }
      });
```

}

Comment: you could force the navigation to happen even when the route has not changed, which is what happens when a user clicks on an active link. Something similar to ** RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})] **

Comment: @Luv ; Your solution works good, but what to do if reloading is expensive??. In all cases I suggest to write your solution as answer. thank you