# Should I use Popper.js + Jquery or Angular Bootstrap module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js

In the question [Can't Toggle Navbar in Bootstrap 4 in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951341/cant-toggle-navbar-in-bootstrap-4-in-angular), an answer presents a way to use Bootstrap 4 in Angular through ngBootstrap, but alternatively one could simply use Popper.js and JQuery. Which of those options is considered the best practice?

Comment: Any option without jQuery. I've been using ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap most of the time. But now, I'm using BS 5 directly and all good